# R2DBC ClassCastException Long cannot cast to Int

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, h2, spring-data-r2dbc

I got the following error below. I try to find where I did it wrong between Long and Int but not found anywhere any idea?

**Log Error**

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'initializer' defined in class path resource [com/abc/checkout/agentoperator/config/H2Configuration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agents ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, store_number INTEGER, country VARCHAR(5), name VARCHAR(255), status VARCHAR(10), last_updated TIMESTAMP ); nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.abc.checkout.agentoperator.AgentOperatorApplicationKt.main(AgentOperatorApplication.kt:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of class path resource [schema.sql]: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agents ( id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, store_number INTEGER, country VARCHAR(5), name VARCHAR(255), status VARCHAR(10), last_updated TIMESTAMP ); nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ScriptUtils.lambda$runStatement$9(ScriptUtils.java:571) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onError(MonoStreamCollector.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onNext(MonoStreamCollector.java:137) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.tryEmitScalar(FluxFlatMap.java:488) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:272) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:230) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:165) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:87) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8466) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(FluxFlatMap.java:93) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4382) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:451) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onNext(FluxConcatMap.java:251) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drainAsync(FluxFlattenIterable.java:421) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.drain(FluxFlattenIterable.java:686) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlattenIterable$FlattenIterableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFlattenIterable.java:250) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:191) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:299) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:337) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onComplete(FluxContextWrite.java:126) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxUsing$UsingConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxUsing.java:549) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BaseSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:460) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:805) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$BufferAsyncSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:753) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drainLoop(FluxCreate.java:247) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.drain(FluxCreate.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxCreate$SerializedFluxSink.complete(FluxCreate.java:204) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils$ReadCompletionHandler.completed(DataBufferUtils.java:986) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferUtils$ReadCompletionHandler.completed(DataBufferUtils.java:917) ~[spring-core-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeUnchecked(Invoker.java:129) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invokeDirect(Invoker.java:160) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:188) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Invoker.invoke(Invoker.java:300) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$ReadTask.completed(WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:477) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl$ReadTask.failed(WindowsAsynchronousFileChannelImpl.java:485) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:389) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl.java:113) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
        at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1707) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
        at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ConnectionFactoryInitializer.execute(ConnectionFactoryInitializer.java:112) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.r2dbc.connection.init.ConnectionFactoryInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(ConnectionFactoryInitializer.java:97) ~[spring-r2dbc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.reactive.context.ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ReactiveWebServerApplicationContext.java:66) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
        at com.abc.checkout.agentoperator.AgentOperatorApplicationKt.main(AgentOperatorApplication.kt:12) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class java.lang.Integer (java.lang.Long and java.lang.Integer are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$summingLong$23(Collectors.java:699) ~[na:na]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoStreamCollector$StreamCollectorSubscriber.onNext(MonoStreamCollector.java:132) ~[reactor-core-3.4.22.jar:3.4.22]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
```

**H2Configuration**

```
@Configuration
class H2Configuration {

    @Bean
    fun initializer(connectionFactory: ConnectionFactory): ConnectionFactoryInitializer {
        val initializer = ConnectionFactoryInitializer()
        initializer.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory)
        val populator = CompositeDatabasePopulator()
        populator.addPopulators(ResourceDatabasePopulator(ClassPathResource("schema.sql")))
        populator.addPopulators(ResourceDatabasePopulator(ClassPathResource("data.sql")))
        initializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator)
        return initializer
    }
}
```

**AgentEntity**

```
@Table("agents")
data class AgentEntity(

    @Id
    @Column("id")
    var id: Long?,

    @Column("store_number")
    var storeNumber: Int,

    @Column("country")
    var country: String,

    @Column("name")
    var name: String,

    @Column("status")
    var status: String,

    @Column("last_update")
    var lastUpdate: OffsetDateTime
)
```

**AgentRepository**

```
@Repository
interface AgentRepository : ReactiveCrudRepository<AgentEntity, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM agents WHERE status = :status")
    fun findAgentByStatus(status: String): Flux<AgentEntity>

    @Query("select * from agents where id = :agentId ")
    fun findByAgentId(agentId: Long): Flux<AgentEntity>
}
```

**data.sql**

```
INSERT INTO agents (id, store_number, country, name, status) VALUES (1, 5019, 'TH', 'devid', 'UP');
INSERT INTO agents (id, store_number, country, name, status) VALUES (2, 5019, 'TH', 'angle', 'DOWN');
INSERT INTO agents (id, store_number, country, name, status) VALUES (3, 5018, 'TH', 'nomad', 'UP');
INSERT INTO agents (id, store_number, country, name, status) VALUES (4, 5018, 'TH', 'iceberg', 'DOWN');
```

**schema.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS agents (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  store_number INTEGER,
  country VARCHAR(5),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  status VARCHAR(10),
  last_updated TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: There is format mismatch `serial` uses `integer` not `long`. Either change data to integer or use `bigserial` in schema.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK if you use `spring boot` < `3.x`, you should better use `0.x` versions of `R2DBC`, in my experience the combination of `spring boot 2.7.4` and `Oracle R2DBC 1.0.0` leads to the same exception. Changing `Oracle R2DBC` from `1.0.0` to `0.4.0` fixed the problem.